# how to cancel a Task when the CancellationTokenSource is not available?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task, cancellation

I have a function, which returns a Task to do anything with that.

I have a custom form, ProgressDialog, whose constructor takes a Task to execute. This dialog displays the state of the Task, but it's not important.

The dialog has a Cancel button. If the user clicks on that, the Task should be canceled, but how can I do this? There I have only the Task object, not the CancellationTokenSource (which I could cancel the Task with).

Why can't I cancel the Task via the Task object itself?

Comment: That is how Task is implemented by MS... another point: The cancellation token allows for "cooperative" cancelling to avoid data loss/corruption... waht's the reason you don't want to use it ?

Comment: It would be practical for the Task to have the CancellationTokenSource property. For me. The reason is in my question. When the user clicks the Cancel button, I'd do something like this:
task.CanncellationTokenSrc.Cancel();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer would be you can't do this.  If you want to cancel something, you need to provide a cancellation token of some form.  The expected pattern is outlined nicely here:

- [Cancellation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364.aspx) (MSDN).